# Why is "Invalid grant: account has been deleted" being returned for accounts that have not actually been deleted?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

We have a live streaming service, and we allow users to connect their YouTube accounts (through an OAuth 2.0 flow) for syndication of their streams from our service to their YouTube channels. We're getting a number of reports of users being unable to connect their accounts, and the response we're getting from Google is "invalid_grant: account has been deleted". We're pretty confident that the accounts in question have not in fact been deleted, as we've been in meetings with the affected clients and have watched as they have successfully logged into the affected accounts. What else can cause such a response?

So far, we've tried having the affected accounts:

- change passwords
- revoke access and reconnect

Neither approach produced any change.